# Auth cookie not persistent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, forms-authentication

I have the following code, and according to other stackoverflow answers, it's supposed to work, but it doesn't. Am I missing something else?

```
DateTime expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30);
if (rememberMe)
{
    expiration = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
}
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();

var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, email, DateTime.Now, expiration, rememberMe,
guid.ToString(), FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);

var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

and reading the cookie in `Application_AuthenticateRequest`

```
var authCookie = Request.Cookies.Get(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName);
if (authCookie == null) return;

var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
if (ticket == null) return;
...
```

and my web.config entry:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Index" timeout="30" /> <!--  30minutes
</authentication>
```

Answer (score 0):

1-In root web.config of your asp.net project, in system.web section, set authentication mode to "Forms" :

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login" timeout="18000" />
    </authentication>
</system.web>
```

2-For persist authentication key use:

```
using System.Web.Security;

FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName,false);
```

3- For read current authentication key use:

```
var userName=controller.User.Identity.Name;
```